# Why not supported font-awesome in firefox browser, after bundles the css file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, font-awesome

i am using font awesome in css during websitework, after css bundles int0 asp.net MVC4 , the font-awesome not rendering in firefox browser? why does not support in firefox and why supporting in chrome. thank you in advance..

Comment: Chances are you're doing something wrong somewhere. Since you're not giving the slightest bit of information about what it is you're doing exactly, I don't think anyone can help you fix it.

Comment: thank u for your help, and for example see this link http://superuser.com/questions/446001/firefox-cannot-render-icons-from-font-awesome-webfont-set

Comment: Well, the question is answered there, with a fix. What more do you need?

Comment: the font awesome is working in firefox when bundles optimization is false. when i enable the bundles optimization is true.. the font awesome in not working in firefox.. that why i asked that.. thank you sir

Comment: Then update your question by [edit]ing it and describe your problem **precisely**.

Comment: bundles.UseCdn = true;

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome/css").Include("~/Content/css/font-awesome.css"));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
sir, here i am using CDN also, when i use this CDN and Bundlesoptimization in asp.net mvc4, when i enable bundle optimization is true, the css file does nor rendering in firefox..

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with font awesome icons not rendering in firefox only and I found out it has to do with the security settings that firefox defaults with. In your browser go to "about:config". Search for "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy". It will be set to TRUE as default. If you double click it then it will flip it to false. Then restart your browser (make sure you close it all the way). The icons should show up fine now.